# How to Get The Selected Item in ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a simple App with a ListView in it.  In the Java code, I'm trying to figure out which item(s) is currently selected.  From the ListView documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html I see there's a method in the ListView class called

```
public void setSelection (int position)
```

I looked for a similarly named method named getSelection(), but there is none.

So, first, how do I determine which item in my ListView is currently selected?  I already have the object for the ListView, so I just need the method to tells me which item the user clicked on.

```
ListView myLV = (ListView) findViewByID(R.id.myListView);
```

Also, can I define a "callback" function which is called whenever an item is selected?

Finally, how can I use the documentation to figure this out?  This is a very basic question which I should be able to figure out on my own.  I did what seems to be the right thing: I looked at the Official Developer pages for the ListView class, but it didn't provide the answer.  How can I answer these (basic) questions for myself?

Comment: Unlike spinner, listview don't have any selected item by default. And you can't select the listview when you are using it alone(i.e you are clicking it). But if you are providing buttons to navigate listitems(i.e), you can make logical selection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  mylv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View v, int position, long lng) {
    String selectedFromList =(String) (mylv.getItemAtPosition(position));

  }                 
});
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but javac complains: cannot find symbol OnItemClickListener.  What else do I have to add in order to do this?

Comment: I tried adding another interface to my main class: public class LinearLayoutDemo extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener but then javac complains: LinearLayoutDemo is not abstract and does not override abstract method onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?>,android.view.View,int,long) in android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Comment: Don't use the click listener.use item click listener for list view.post your full list view coding..

Comment: Okay, got it.  That works.  I'll clean my code and post full demo.

Answer (score 1):

> I looked for a similarly named method named getSelection(), but there is none. So, first, how do I determine which item in my ListView is currently selected?

The super class AdapterView has [`getSelectedItem()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29), along with `getSelectedItemId()` and others. AbsListView has [`getSelectedView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getSelectedView%28%29) too. But these only tend to work when you have used [`setChoiceMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29)

The [OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) lets you know which it is clicked as it is clicked.

> Finally, how can I use the documentation to figure this out?

You were right to start in ListView's documentation, but go to the ["Inherited Methods"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#inhmethods) section and check the super classes as well.

Comment: But there is no selection for listview right..if we don't setChoiceMode(), because It is contrary to listview's behavior..What do you think..? i.e we will get the selected item until its event(on itemclick ) completes, once its event completes then there is no selection

Comment: My initial answer didn't mention you need to use `setChoiceMode()` to enable selections, but I quickly added it, because as you said ListViews won't retain a selection by default. Of course OnItemClickListeners can track the "selected" item without `setChoiceMode()`.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I added myLV.setChoiceMode(SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE); and I have compilation errors:  It can't find symbol SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE

Comment: If I add myLV.setChoiceMode(0x00000001); then no compilation errors, but when I tap an item on the ListView, it doesn't stay selected.  And myLV.getSelectedItemId() returns a very large negative number.

Comment: I also tried this: long id1 = myLV.getSelectedId() but javac can't find the symbol getSelectedId.  Seems like all my errors are similar: javac can't find whatever.  What am I doing wrong.  Am I not importing the right java class?

Comment: @JB_User 1) I'm guessing it didn't recognize the variable since it's from another class try: `myLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE);` 2) The id depends on your adapter, it should work great for CursorAdapters. 3) `getSelectedId()` is a typo, it should be `getSelectedItemId()`. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position by using onitem click listener.by using on item click listener you can get position of selected item in the list.And you can put this position in Toast